# How can I implement random smooth with common trajectory and different scale in R mgcv package?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I am trying to implement a special case of generalized additive mixed model using R mgcv package without success and in need of advice.

Specifically, the model has mixed effect of levels which scales common smooth link function (please see the [attached figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUlFc.png)). In other words, the model has random smooth with common trajectory (curvature) but differently scaled.

I have already tried

```
gam(y ~ te(level,x,bs=c('re','tp'),k=3))
```

where level denotes a factor variable denoting levels with mixed effects, and x denotes a continuous variable. But this results in smooth link function with different trajectory.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that's not a GAM (having the product of a coefficient with a smooth makes predictions a nonlinear function of the parameters).  You can probably get some advice on ways to make it one on stats.stackexchange.com, or maybe suggestions that you need an iterative approach to fitting:  fix the betas, fit the smooth; fix the smooth, fit the betas; repeat.

Comment: Can you explain the model you want a bit more; one wouldn't use beta notation for a random effect. The model you show is a varying coefficient model, but in that model the beta_1 is a fixed linear *slope* that is modified by a smooth of x, which for continuous level and x would be `s(x, by = level)`, but you say level is a factor and you can't smooth a factor. But you are talking about random smooths which would be done via `s(x, level, bs = 'fs')`.

Comment: @user2554330 thank you for clearly explaining that my model is not a GAM by definition. Probably that's why gam() can't afford what I want. The iterative algorithm you suggested would work, but is beyond my skill in statistics and coding. That's why I would like to know if there's a way to force some constraint on the two-dimensional smooth to achieve my model.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thank you for the question that clarify the problem. "level" variable is a factor. `s(level,bs='re')` is for random intercept, `s(x,by=level)` for random smooth. From what I have tried `s(level,x,bs=c('re','tp'))` results in something not far from `s(x,by=level)`, as "level" axis is treated as random effect. I thought there may be a way to make some constraint on the two-dimensional smooth to express varying coefficient model (thank you again for letting me know the term).

Comment: @GavinSimpson Could you explain what is `bs='fs'`? Maybe you meant `bs='sf'`? If so, why is soap film smooth more appropriate than other types of smooth in this case? Also, could you suggest more appropriate notation for beta_1?

Comment: I mean't `bs = 'fs'`; it is a fully penalized factor smooth interaction but all smooths (one per subject) share the same wiggliness as there's only one smoothness parameter. It's basically the smooth equivalent of a random slope plus intercept model, with the slopes replaced by smooths. We explain more here: https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876

Comment: You wouldn't use \beta_{1i} for a random effect as that's the notation for fixed effect parameters. Also what is the subscript i indexing? You'll need to explain more about what you really want to fit as I'm pretty familiar with these kinds of GAM models but I'm unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: What notation you would use depends on what you intend to fit, what model.

Comment: From your description it looks like you want `bs = 'fs'`, where `s(x, f, bs = 'fs')` is the same as `t2(x, f, bs = c('tp', 're'), full = TRUE)` where `f` is the grouping factor, but note that is not a varying coefficient model and it also doesn't match your notation in the equation in the image.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thank you for the clear explanation. Now I understood that mgcv doesn't support what I want to do, and it wasn't a GAM in the first place. I will try some other way of fitting. i = level = f, by the way.

Comment: Just to be clear; the model you wrote is a varying coefficient model and that is a special case of a penalised GAM which mgcv does support. It's unclear what you mean by scale and curvature; sounds like you want each curve to have the same shape, just shifted up or down. If you did that on the log scale, then you'd also get scaling of the shape. If so, `gam(log(y) ~ s(level, bs = 're') + s(x))` or `gam(y ~ s(level, bs = 're') + s(x)), family = gaussian(link = 'log'))` depending on whether you want the errors to be multiplicative or additive

Comment: Curvature has special meaning in these models; it means the second derivative of the smooth and is used for the default smoothness penalty in most smooth types. You can therefore fit this model: `gam(y ~ s(x, level, bs = 'fs'))` and that will result in a random smooths that have the same curvature but not the same shape, where curvature has the meaning of second derivative or what we like to call wiggliness.

Comment: If the log versions of those models aren't quite what you want (and I can see how that may be the case), then no, *mgcv* can't handle those models as they aren't additive in the linear predictor beyond the exceptions that *mgcv* can handle (varying coef models) and I'm not aware of any software that can jointly handle the non-linear predictor and the random effects like that.

Comment: @GavinSimpson In `y = beta{0} + beta{1,level}*smooth(x) + e`, beta{1,level} is a random coefficient that differs across level = [1,2,..., k], and multiplies common smooth(x). The resulting second term has the same shape for all levels, except differently stretched (scaled) for each level. In other words I want to change linear slope `y = beta{0} + beta{1,level}*x + e` into non-linear smooth. Or, I want something like `gam(y ~ s(level, bs = 're')*s(x))`, which of course doesn't work in itself.

Comment: @GavinSimpson `gam(y ~ s(level, bs = 're') + s(x)), family = gaussian(link = 'log'))` seems to achieve what I want. Thank you!
Actually however, my full model is`y = beta{0} + beta{1,level}*smooth(x1) + beta{2,level}*x2 + e` and I skipped the third term to avoid complication. The log link function seems inapplicable to the full model...